# SharePoint content-length limit on POST

Tags: web-part, sharepoint-online

Is there any limit on Content-Length when POST in SharePoint (Online version).

I'm using web part form, and when the data is too many, any submission on form will result in web part error.

When reduce the data it becomes normal.

So is there a limit on form size? Any work-around for this?

Comment: Are you uploading some files or is it with normal form with text data ?

Comment: @Khatri: Just normal text, label, literal control for binding HTML code, no uploading files

Comment: I think there is a limit of 80KB each time SharePoint form do a POST. If POST size bigger, web part error will occur.

Comment: How much text are you POSTing ?

Comment: If I bind a 80KB text to a Label control (just Label, not text box), and POST (for example, Save), web part error will occur.